# Maximum value of a given integral

Tags: integration

For $a,b∈R$,  and $b>a$,  what is the maximum possible value of the integral
$$\int_{a}^{b}7x-x^2-10dx?$$
I have no idea how to solve it. Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: it is a parabola facing down and the integral represents the "signed" area. So look for the interval when the parabola lies above the $x-$axis.

Comment: You want to integrate everywhere the function is above the $x$ axis and nowhere than it isn't.  Find the correct $a,b$ to make that happen.

Comment: I can't understand by "signed" area. @Anurag A

Comment: By "signed" area I mean the value of the integral represents the area with a + or - sign, depending on if the curve is above or below the $x-$axis. Since you want maximize the value of the integral, you don't want portions which can give you a negative area.

Answer (score 3):

If you integrate over the region where $7x-x^2-10$ is negative, the value will be less.

If you integrate over the region where the $7x-x^2-10$ is positive, the value will increase.

[image]

Hence we want to solve the problem of $$7x-x^2-10\geq 0$$

$$x^2-7x+10 \leq 0$$

$$(x-2)(x-5) \leq 0$$

One should be able to tell the value of $a$ and $b$ from on top and substitue it to evaluate the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks sir. I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=7x-x^2-10$ we have $f(x)=-(x-5)(x-2)$ thus $2,5$ are the roots of this function.Between these roots the curve is above x-axis.Thus $a=2,b=5$ thus maximum possible are is $\frac{9}{2}$.